# Acceptable Time Frame for Dead-End Job

Tags: careers, resignation

I'm currently in a part-time job at a mid-size company. It is a professional position despite being part-time, and I took it for the experience (I'm in the early stages of my career) and the promise of possibly being promoted to full-time, but after a year I'm finding it to be dissatisfying.

The organization is poorly run, my supervisor is ineffectual, and it appears that there will never be enough in the budget for our area to ever promote me. Plus my supervisor is not really capable of advocating for me, even though I do think he's a nice guy. And yet the workload is ever-expanding and I am taking on more and more responsibility.

I've been using my extra time to do small freelance projects, take professional development courses, and do improvement projects for our area. I think I'm doing a pretty good job maxing out the potential of this role.

My question is, is a year too short a time period to consider leaving? Will it be frowned upon by other employers? Or, better yet, will the experience be considered insubstantial?

Should I wait? I've read that 18 months is the minimum. Is there any merit to this? Because I'm ready to leave for greener pastures.

Comment: You expect promotion from nothing in just a year when everything you have to say is negative?

Comment: I would not say I've done nothing. I have made measurable improvements to our department's processes and workflow (which were disastrous to begin with) and taken on projects above my station. I've also engaged in professional development and of course performed my usual responsibilities with excellence. I also get along well with my colleagues and even my supervisor. I would just like to be promoted to full time in order to have more time to get things done. I don't think that's particularly entitled. The position should never have been part time to begin with.

Comment: I stayed for a few months short of two years in a similar situation and wish I'd left sooner. You said you have some free time so you should find it easy to start sending out your CV.

Answer (score 8):

It's a part-time job for crissake! You are most likely getting zero benefits and you probably wouldn't wish the pay you've got on your most mean spirited, sadistic professor. You probably learned everything there is to learn about your job long before your year was over, too.

Low pay, zero benefits, no more growing in that job, no career prospects  - unless you want to continue living like this, I suggest that you end this charade and move on with your life.

One more time: 18 months at your dead end job is way different from 18 months at Google. If you spent less than 24 months at Google, recruiters will look at you strangely - that's because Google is a great firm. If you spend more than six months pumping gas, recruiters will look at you strangely and wondering why you like pumping gas so much that you didn't look for a better job. When you're getting advice, pay attention to the context of the advice. In this case, the context is full-time, professional employment with professional pay and benefits to match. And right now, this context is missing from your job.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's true that I should have more perspective.

Comment: I will say that my current position is a professional one in my field. It's just low level (at least as far as compensation.) So, not exactly gas pumper or barista. Part of the reason I asked this question is because I want the experience I'm gaining to "count." But I suppose I'm overthinking and should just prepare to move on to a real job. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "long enough to land another job". If you've got a contract I'd add "depending on your contract terms".

There's a lot of jobs that are short term (I'm on one now!) and while clearly you don't have faith in your supervisor the fact that you have an "ever increasing workload" and "more and more responsibility" are signs they have faith in you.

If you're ready, start looking, and once your aquatic fowl are aligned, go for it!